# Restart Novell Remote Manager (NetWare)

Tags: novell

Is there an easy way to restart the Novell Remote Manager on NetWare? I tried to unload/release HTTPSTKD.nlm but there are WAY too many dependencies.

I've tried many different variations of http(s)://ip:8008(8009) and to no avail. I think the daemon is simply not responding.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the latest service-pack it isn't really able to be done without a reboot. It hooks too many modules that unloading them all effectively takes the server down anyway. You can restart it from within NRM, but if you're locked out for some reason your only recourse is to reboot it.